# iOS - Open multiple same viewcontroller for multiple uilocalnotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uilocalnotification

This is what i want to achieve

Let's say there were 3 uilocalnotification for different events. User have not launched the app yet. One reminder was at 12:40pm, 2nd 12:44 pm and third: 12:48pm. User got an sms, User opened SMS app and notification went away (off course phone is not locked now). Now app should show 3 on icon badge and when User open the app, it should pop up all three viewcontroller one after another.Also if the app is active all the viewcontroller should popup. Starting with 12:48pm event, than 12:44 and than 12:40pm. User can close the event or snooze again depends on user choice.The count of the icon should now become 0.

Currently achieved:

1) Multiple notifications are received but only 1 badge count appears.

2) On launching the app by tapping on icon the main viewcontroller appears and not the notificationviewcontroller also the badge count stays to 1

3) If the app is launched by tapping the localnotification from notificationcenter only 1 view controller appears the rest two notifications are lost...

Solutions please...

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain badge count on server side. It is almost impossible to handle it offline. Also if you have got 3 notifications in notificationcenter, on opening any 1 notification and then setting badge count to 0 will clear all your notifications from notificationcenter which is default behaviour. Avoid using Badge counts in local notifications.

Comment: I am using [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/calminder-date-reminders/id449498828?mt=8)...it has most of my requirement...and notification badge count works perfectly...that is if the app is in background and i have received the notification...the badge count increases

Comment: Are you setting badge count to 0 on opening 1st notification?